# Citing a Datasheet or Technical document in IEEE style

Tags: citations, citation-style, ieee

I am working on a thesis in the Engineering field and I came across the problem of citing *datasheets, technical documents, test reports, application notes, reference designs*... that the manufacturers of integrated circuits publish.

The problem to cite those documents in IEEE style are:

- Usually there is no author, but a company (e.g. *Texas Instruments*)
- These documents are not a book, article... with a clearly defined citation template
- They are usually identified by a code (e.g. *[LM555](http://www.ti.com/product/LM555)*) that corresponds to the integrated circuit part number. Finding the document on the internet is easier searching for the specific code (*LM555*) than for the title of the document or part (*Highly Stable 555 Timer*)

Therefore, I think that incluiding the part number or code is essential for providing a good reference, but I don't know how to insert it in the citation, plus, reference tracking software like Zotero or EndNote do not include any special field for storing this codes.

So far the resources I have found on the topic are:

- [Monash University datasheet citation gide in IEEE style](http://guides.lib.monash.edu/c.php?g=219786&p=5937317)
- [Tex StackExchange question on standards and datasheet citation with no author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42501)
- [Victoria University standards and patents citation guide in IEEE style](http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/standardsandpatents)

For further clarification, the types of documents I would like to cite are:

- Datasheet LM555 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf
- Test Report PMP21771 http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidt117/tidt117.pdf

Any suggestions on how to cite appropriately these documents or how to store them in a citation software will be very much appreciated. Please, share your views on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cite datasheets as manuals. For example, I recently cited the LTC3600. My experience is with biblatex and JabRef. In JabRef I can choose the 'manual' type and can fill in the organisation, datasheet title, url, and use a (part) number. I believe that most citation managers have a field for 'number', you can use this for part codes.

The resultant biblatex code can look like this:

```
@Manual{ltc3600,
  title        = {{15V}, {1.5A} Synchronous Rail-to-Rail Single Resistor Step-Down Regulator},
  year         = {2011},
  number       = {LTC3600},
  note         = {Rev. D},
  organization = {Linear Technology},
  url          = {https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3600fd.pd},
}
```

And the output in IEEE style like this:

[image]

I believe this is similar to the Tex SE answer you linked.